# Nginx – Закрыть доступ к .php из веб, но оставить возможность выполнения для localhost

Tags: php, nginx, config

Есть готовое приложение на PHP(личный кабинет), которое я встроил в свой сайт. Всё работает прекрасно, но **все .php открыты**, то есть любой желающий может по прямому адресу открыть исполняемый, например **/admin.php**.
Сам сайт работает на **Nginx + PHP7.0-fpm**. Из условий только два сервера, которые работают в паре, обращаются друг к другу и обмениваются данными, если это необходимо.

Что только не пробовал уже.. И разные регулярки путей для Nginx, вариант с satisfy any со списком разрешённых ip, и вообще убрать секцию, всё время всё работает не так.

Проблема в том, что если секция выглядит так:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @php;
    }
}
location ^~ /webapp/* {
    deny all;
}

location @php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

То приложение нормально работает, все .php внутри папки /webapp/ выполняются, но доступ к ним открыт по прямой ссылке. А так же **лог nginx заваливает ошибками**, что пользователь не может получить изображение из **/webapp/img/** хотя в самом приложении изображение показывается.. Если же изменить на что-то другое, то .php перестают выполняться, но сервер правильно отдаёт 403.

Секция nginx с которой я экспериментирую:

```
location /webapp/ {
    satisfy any;

    allow 1.1.1.1; # ip первого сервера
    allow 2.2.2.2; # ip второго сервера
    allow 127.0.0.1/8;

    deny all;

    autoindex off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;

    location ^~ /(img|icons)/ {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю неправильно и как добиться работающего приложения при закрытых файлах из вне.

Comment: Показанный вами конфиг никак не может выполнять php-код. Покажите части конфига, связанные с php, а дальше посмотрим

Comment: @andreymal внёс изменения в первый пост, извиняюсь.

Comment: Ну, рядом с `try_files /does_not_exists @php;` нужные allow/deny и пишите? Или даже внутри `location @php` (точно не уверен)

Comment: у вас файлы php отдаются клиенту как обычный текстовый файл? или в чем ошибка то?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev нет, они выполняются как скрипты и в браузере выглядят как интерфейс. То есть, к примеру, в /admin.php любой желающий видит функционал вроде.. Изменить счет, cбросить пароль и другой админский функционал. Всё это без стилей, голые четбоксы, но то что туда есть доступ у всех не является нормальным. Пока что решил проблему через подтверждение паролем любых действий.